# How do I troubleshoot Flutter desktop not running on Windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, virtualbox, desktop, flutter-desktop

I have a fresh VM running Windows 10 Pro in Virtualbox, updated with Flutter installed.

Windows Flutter apps will not launch, and I can't seem to find any information through the error message.

**flutter devices**

```
1 connected device:

Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804]
```

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.27.0-4.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.27.0-4.0.pre at C:\tools\flutter
    • Framework revision f8cd24de95 (7 days ago), 2021-02-16 11:24:17 -0800
    • Engine revision 1d537824d6
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-30.0.dev)

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.6)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.8.31019.35
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.0

[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Merritt\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804]

• No issues found!
```

**flutter create myapp**

```
Creating project myapp...
  myapp\.gitignore (created)
  myapp\.idea\libraries\Dart_SDK.xml (created)
  myapp\.idea\libraries\KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
  myapp\.idea\modules.xml (created)
  myapp\.idea\runConfigurations\main_dart.xml (created)
  myapp\.idea\workspace.xml (created)
  myapp\.metadata (created)
  myapp\android\app\build.gradle (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\myapp\MainActivity.kt (created)
  myapp\android\build.gradle (created)
  myapp\android\myapp_android.iml (created)
  myapp\android\.gitignore (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\launch_background.xml (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\values-night\styles.xml (created)
  myapp\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  myapp\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties (created)
  myapp\android\gradle.properties (created)
  myapp\android\settings.gradle (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.swift (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Runner-Bridging-Header.h (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (created)
  myapp\ios\.gitignore (created)
  myapp\ios\Flutter\AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
  myapp\ios\Flutter\Debug.xcconfig (created)
  myapp\ios\Flutter\Release.xcconfig (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\Contents.json (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@2x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@3x.png (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\README.md (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\Main.storyboard (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner\Info.plist (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
  myapp\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\xcshareddata\WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings (created)
  myapp\lib\main.dart (created)
  myapp\myapp.iml (created)
  myapp\pubspec.yaml (created)
  myapp\README.md (created)
  myapp\test\widget_test.dart (created)
  myapp\windows\.gitignore (created)
  myapp\windows\CMakeLists.txt (created)
  myapp\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\CMakeLists.txt (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\flutter_window.cpp (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\flutter_window.h (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\main.cpp (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\resource.h (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\resources\app_icon.ico (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\runner.exe.manifest (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\Runner.rc (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\run_loop.cpp (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\run_loop.h (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\utils.cpp (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\utils.h (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\win32_window.cpp (created)
  myapp\windows\runner\win32_window.h (created)
Running "flutter pub get" in myapp...                            1,153ms
Wrote 90 files.

All done!
In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd myapp
  $ flutter run

To enable null safety, type:

  $ cd myapp
  $ dart migrate --apply-changes

Your application code is in myapp\lib\main.dart.
```

**cd myapp**

**flutter run -d windows**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
Lost connection to device.
Activating Dart DevTools...                                      1,403ms
```

^ Hangs indefinitely

**Running in VSCode**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50470/laIfc9Hl43s=/ws
Error handling 'checkPlatformOverride' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.platformOverride
Error handling 'checkBrightnessOverride' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.brightnessOverride
Error handling 'serviceExtension' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.inspector.setPubRootDirectories
Error handling 'checkIsWidgetCreationTracked' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.inspector.isWidgetCreationTracked
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I am at a loss as to what to try next, and this exact setup works fine in VMWare, just not Virtualbox - and VMWare has been giving me no end of headaches.

Comment: can you try ```flutter run -v -d windows ```

Comment: Sure. It's long, so I made a gist of it: https://gist.github.com/Merrit/6676b5d47a3c5bdb5eb7d83dee3beddc

Comment: sorry its mostly about the compilation it is not very helpful in fact.